# Sonata Admin Advance Filter Customization in DataGridFilter

Tags: filtering, sonata-admin, symfony-3.2

I am using sonata admin for my project as backend.

I have a module and where i have status in the filter like below :

```
$datagridMapper->add('status', '', array('label' => 'Status','field_type' => 'choice','field_options' => array('choices'=> array('Complete' => 1, 'Pending' => 0,'Error' => 2))));
```

It is working fine but in advance filter I got arithmetic filters which looks weird for filtering functionality.

Here i attach that image how it looks like:

[image]

I want to remove that arithmetic filters and want to put my own there , OR i want to hide that filter for that module only.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Advanced filters depends on rendering type. I think what you looking for is something similiar which is implemented for example in `Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Filter\ChoiceFilter`, you see there in `getRenderSettings()` variable settings `operator_type`. This determine which operators are set in advanced filtering.

I didn't found way how to simple override this settings from AdminClas, but you can extends Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\Filter\ChoiceType and create new type with your defined settings for advanced filtering.

Btw. if you filter status by database field, by example Doctrine, then setting settings then you can simple do (settings second parameter):

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('status', 'doctrine_orm_choice', ..
```

Which will solve your problem.